# After restart ibus, can't use it in wine application

Tags: linux, wine, ibus

When working on linux (*mint mate 17.2*), need kill `ibus` daemon and restart it for some reason.

After that one of the editor which is a `wine` application can't use the ibus input anymore, while other non-wine application could.

Trying to restart the `wine` application or `ibus` again won't fix the problem. Restart the machine fixes the issue, but it's not preferred.

Wondering is it due to some kind of cache in wine or wine application.

So, any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution.

### **Solution**

Run `ibus-setup`, then choose yes when tip whether start ibus.

This way the wine application could also use ibus.

---

### Tips

Previously, I use `ibus-daemon &` to start ibus, and wine can't use it.

Not sure, what trick `ibus-setup` did.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interesting, adding option "--xim" to ibus-setup works for me. This is revealed by examining source code of ibus-setup's main.py. This is precisely the "trick" mentioned by @Eric Wang (thanks for the hint in the first place).

Running Fedora 31 ibus-1.5.21-3.fc31, wine-staging 3.21 and 4.20.

By the way, the idea of running ibus-daemon via ibus-setup no longer works; now closing ibus-setup will cause ibus-daemon to quit as well. The commit in question is https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/32572618cdcc36162b5769eb4c71964db9734061 "bus: Exit ibus-daemon with parent's death".